# Windows 7 ISO not booting from DVD drive?

Tags: windows-7

I've downloaded Windows 7 x64 Pro Upgrade from the volume license center. I've also downloaded the  Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool. I'll burn it using this tool and while it will show up in Explorer as if the burn worked correctly, when I try to boot to the DVD on startup, I get a "No operating system found" error (this is a newer Lenovo).

My Ubuntu Live CD works fine, am I  missing something? I read that there's problems if you try to burn a 64bit copy from a 32bit computer, but I'm currently running Win7x64, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I've also tried burning with ImgBurn and Windows 7 built ISO burner, no success. Obviously there's a step I'm missing here, what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The ISO works when I boot from a USB and from PXE. For whatever reason the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool is not creating a bootable DVD. After some more googling I've found other people complaining about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISO is not a boot CD. As this is an upgrade, you already need an operating system compatible with the upgrade CD from which to launch the installation.

The [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool help](http://store.microsoft.com/help/iso-tool) says:

> When your Windows 7 ISO file is copied
>   onto your chosen media, install
>   Windows 7 by moving to the root folder
>   of your DVD or USB flash drive, and
>   then double-click Setup.exe.

which is the procedure that you should follow.

When the CD is for both 32-bit and 64-bit, you might find setup files named setup32.exe or setup64.exe. So choose the correct one.

Comment: Why would it boot when using the USB option? Also I've booted from upgraded dvds before, it is the only way to format the machine. As the MS volume licensing portal gives the same ISO for full and upgrade, I don't think there's any difference.

Comment: Try it from Windows and see if it is working, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The error you is usually related to a hard drive which is not bootable, not an optical disk.

If I was you, I would double check that you are actually booting from the optical drive (and the correct one at that - if you have more than two) - try changing the order in the BIOS.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue because his Ubuntu Live CD boots.  So more than likely the boot order is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is this by any chance the student version?  If so you can make the installation disk by following these [instructions.](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/10/22/how-to-make-a-dvd-of-that-student-only-windows-7/)